# How to prevent data lost due to spot instance terminaton

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop2, oozie

I am using a cluster in which name nodes are spot instances. I have /user/oozie/share/lib/ data on these namenodes. Since these are spot instances, it gets terminated any time due to which missing block error occurs and it corrupts that library. For fixing it I need to create share lib again. How to prevent this issue.

Comment: Have you looked at using `Termination Notice`? This amazon blog can help you with the details about it: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-spot-instance-termination-notices/. Your solution would be: backup the `/user/oozie/share/lib/` in S3 frequently and when you get the Termination notice, take a final backup and stop all operations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

- create EBS volume;
- when you launch the new spot instance (manually or
  automatic) - attache this EBS to the instance;
- write the script which will be mounting this EBS volume to the /user/oozie/share/lib/ directory inside the EC2 instance;
- put this script to the "User data" when you launch this instance;